# this is an recursive solution for finding number of subsets (having sum of elements equal to the given sum) of a set. why it is only returning 1?

Tags: recursion, set

```cpp
//this approach is based on finding all the subsets of a set having n elements by finding subsets of n-1 elements. and so on through recursion..
int sum_subset(int set[], vector<int>& subset, int sum, int n, int l=0)
{
    //for  edge case of sum=0
    if (sum = 0) return 1;
    int s = 0;

    //base condition of recursion
    if (l == n) {
        for (int x:subset) {
            s += x;
        }
        return (s==sum)? 1: 0;
    }
    //calling the recursion for ->not including the nth element of the set of n elements in the subset of n-1 elements
    int a = sum_subset(set, subset, sum, n, l+1);

    //including nth element in the subset
    subset.push_back(set[l]);
    
    //calling the recursion for -> including the nth element of the set of n elements in the subset of n-1 elements
    int b = sum_subset(set, subset, sum, n, l+1);
    return a + b;
}  

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "enter the size of set" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int set[n];
    cout << "enter the set elements" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> set[i];
    }
    cout << "enter the sum " << endl;
    int sum;
    cin >> sum;

    vector<int> subset{0};
    int ans = sum_subset(set, subset, sum, n);
    cout << "subsets having sum =" << sum << "are->" << ans << endl;

}
```

```
//output
enter the size of set
5
enter the set elements
1
2
2
1
3
enter the sum 
3
subsets having sum =3are->1
```

Comment: Please show how you call this function.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov, plz check I had added the function call section.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your `sum` variable the value 0 instead of comparing the values:

```cpp
    //for  edge case of sum=0
    if (sum = 0) return 1;
    int s = 0;
```

This itself hides another problem: you never remove the values from the `subset` vector. For example, the first time you push the value into your subset, you leave your subset equal to `{3}`. Then you just add more and more values, and this "subset" will never give you the sum equal 3.

One more problem that doesn't affect your program, but is important. In the line below you don't create an empty vector, but you create a vector with one zero element in it, the the vector is equal to `{0}`:

```cpp
vector<int> subset{0};
```